# how can call 4 different HTML sub-pages with checkboxes and one button

Tags: javascript

I have 4 checkboxes to select which HTML sub-page should be loaded. Pressing a button loads the page. Only one checkbox should be selected. Can someone help me?

```js
function selectOnlyThis(id){
  var myCheckbox = document.getElementsByName("myCheckbox");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(myCheckbox,function(el){
   el.checked = false;
  });
  id.checked = true;
}

function check(){ 
    var id = document.getElementById("c1").checked;
  //var id = document.getElementById("c2").checked;
  //var id = document.getElementById("c3").checked;
  //var id = document.getElementById("c4").checked;
  alert(id);
}

document.getElementById("id").onclick = function() {check()};
  //open File.html
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="myCheckbox" value="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="myCheckbox" value="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="myCheckbox" value="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="myCheckbox" value="4" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>

<button id="c1" onclick="check()">OpenHTML</button>
```

Comment: you can use window.open four times in your function

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but it sounds like if you only want one page to be selected you need to use radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "radio" controls, they are intended for unique option selection. Also you don't need a function to uncheck/check items, it's automatic with radio buttons.

```js
function check(){ 
  alert(document.forms['selection'].myCheckbox.value);
}

window.document.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("id").onclick = function() {check()};
  //open File.html
   }
```

```html
<form name=selection>
<input type="radio" id="c1" name="myCheckbox" value="1"  />
<input type="radio" id="c2" name="myCheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="c3" name="myCheckbox" value="3" />
<input type="radio" id="c4" name="myCheckbox" value="4" />
</form>
<button id="c1" onclick="check()">OpenHTML</button>
```

Comment: ah, super thank you. Where can I add the 4 different links? right here?

Comment: <input type="radio" id="c1" name="myCheckbox" onclick="window.location.href='Link.html';" value="1"/>

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check(){ 
  //alert(document.forms['action'].myCheckbox.value);
         (document.forms['action'].myCheckbox.value);
 }
```

```html
<form name=action>
  <input type="radio" id="c1" name="myCheckbox" onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com'"/>         
  <input type="radio" id="c2" name="myCheckbox" value="window.location.href='http://yahoo.com'"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c3" name="myCheckbox" value="3"/>  
  <input type="radio" id="c4" name="myCheckbox" value="4"/>
  </form>
    
<button onclick="check()">OpenHTML</button>
```

this is running, thanks

```js
function check(){ 
         window.open(document.forms['action'].myCheckbox.value);  
  
 }
```

```html
<form name=action>
<input type="radio" id="c1" name="myCheckbox" value="http://google.com" onclick="myCheckbox(this.value)"/>        
<input type="radio" id="c2" name="myCheckbox" value="http://yahoo.com" onclick="myCheckbox(this.value)"/>
<form>

<button onclick="check()">OpenHTML</button>
```